# Kendo ui grid - Change row template content dynamically

Tags: kendo-ui, kendo-grid

I came across this, and i really don´t know how to change it. I have column field like this:

```
{ field: "nome", title: "Nome", width: "20px", template: '<span><img id=idIconRowFolder src="icon_rowFolder.png" style="float: left;width: 20%;height: 16px;width: 16px;margin-top: 2%;"/></span><a href="\\#" class="k-button link">#= nome #</a>',hideMe: true},
```

As you can see, i´m using a template and inside it there´s an image...it´s basically a icon that appears on the left side of the text in each row. **What i want is to change this icon dinamically**, so i know i have to use the dataBound function, and iterate through rows, and i´m actually doing this, but i don´t know how to access the template and his content:

my dataBound:

```
           var grid = this;
           grid.tbody.find('>tr').each(function()
           {
             var dataItem = grid.dataItem(this);
             console.log(dataItem);

             if(dataItem.tipo === 'pdf')
              {

                 "what do i do here" ?
              }
           });
```

Thanks for your time, regards.

**EDIT:**

Hi everyone, thanks to your suggestions, i found a way, here it is for someone who could have the same problem:(in the databound put this)

```
var grid = $("#gridBaseDados").data("kendoGrid");
$(grid.tbody).find('tr').each(function () 
{
   var dataItem = grid.dataItem(this).tipo;
   var ficheiroValExtension = dataItem.split('.').pop();
   if(ficheiroValExtension === 'pdf')
    {
      $(this).find('img').prop('src',  'index.hyperesources/icon_rowPdf.png').css('width','17px').css('height','22px');
    } 
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please try with the below code snippet.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>Jayesh Goyani</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://kendo.cdn.telerik.com/2015.3.1111/styles/kendo.common.min.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://kendo.cdn.telerik.com/2015.3.1111/styles/kendo.rtl.min.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://kendo.cdn.telerik.com/2015.3.1111/styles/kendo.default.min.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://kendo.cdn.telerik.com/2015.3.1111/styles/kendo.mobile.all.min.css">

    <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.9.1.min.js"></script>
    <script src="http://kendo.cdn.telerik.com/2015.3.1111/js/angular.min.js"></script>
    <script src="http://kendo.cdn.telerik.com/2015.3.1111/js/jszip.min.js"></script>
    <script src="http://kendo.cdn.telerik.com/2015.3.1111/js/kendo.all.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>

    <div id="Grid">
    </div>
    <script>
        $(document).ready(function () {
            $("#Grid").kendoGrid({
                dataSource: {
                    type: "odata",
                    transport: {
                        read: "http://demos.kendoui.com/service/Northwind.svc/Orders",
                        dataType: "jsonp"
                    },
                    schema: {
                        model: {
                            fields: {
                                OrderID: { type: "number" },
                                Freight: { type: "number" },
                                ShipName: { type: "string" },
                                OrderDate: { type: "date" },
                                ShipCity: { type: "string" }
                            }
                        }
                    },
                    pageSize: 10,
                    serverPaging: true,
                    serverFiltering: true,
                    serverSorting: true
                },
                dataBound: onDataBound,
                filterable: true,
                sortable: true,
                pageable: true,
                columns: [{
                    field: "OrderID",
                    filterable: false
                },
                                "Freight",
                                {
                                    field: "OrderDate",
                                    title: "Order Date",
                                    width: 120,
                                    format: "{0:MM/dd/yyyy}"
                                }, {
                                    field: "ShipName",
                                    title: "Ship Name",
                                    width: 260
                                }, {
                                    field: "ShipCity",
                                    title: "Ship City",
                                    template: '<img id=idIconRowFolder src="icon_rowFolder.png" style="float: left;width: 20%;height: 16px;width: 16px;margin-top: 2%;"/>'
                                }
                ]
            });
        });
        function onDataBound(e) {
            var grid = $("#Grid").data("kendoGrid");

            $(grid.tbody).find('tr').each(function () {
                $(this).find('img').prop('src', 'Your new image src');

                //Below syntax will return orderID
                //$($(this).find('td').get(0)).html()
            });
        }
    </script>
</body>
</html>
```

Let me know if any concern.

Comment: Thanks for answering Jayesh but this is changing all my rows icons into the new one, i want to change with the logic that i wrote above...if "tipo" is === pdf THEN the icon changes, how do i perform that?

Answer (score 1):

As i understand you want to show specific image corresponding to each data item. Then you have two options:

1.Additional field in dataSource that represents `img.src`

```
{
    field: "nome",
    title: "Nome",
    width: "20px",
    template: '<span><img src="#=imgSrc#" .../></span><a href="\\#" class="k-button link">#= nome #</a>',
    hideMe: true
}
```

2.Use clientSide function that return image source dependent on data item:

```
{
    field: "nome",
    title: "Nome",
    width: "20px",
    template: '<span><img src="#=getImgSrc(data)#" .../></span><a href="\\#" class="k-button link">#= nome #</a>',
    hideMe: true
}
```

and function itself:

```
var getImgSrc = function(item)
{
    if(item.tipo === 'pdf') { return ... }
    ...
}
```

**Update:** of course for that no need to iterate `dataSource` in `dataBound` event

Comment: @Japi what should i see there?

Comment: You can see how to use templates. @Gene R solution is correct. I would suggest you to use external template for this.

Comment: @Japi well external template with `if` statements could be as third option

Comment: R Yeah, and whole html and javascript would be in same place

Comment: Gene R, thanks for answering, i never use this method before, so i´m a little confused. This #=getImgSrc(data)# is a function that is called everytime as i understand, but then i´ve done what you wrote below, and the function is not called...could you teach me a little bit more? thanks